# Google Apps Scripts - Issue running script when sharing Spreadsheet with view only

Tags: gwt, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-api

I created a spreadsheet app using the Script Editor.
The users who I share it with are not that technical and I don't want them able to open the Script Editor and change anything, be it on accident or on purpose.

If they don't have access to edit the file then the script does not work (it basically launches a sidebar). I want the users to be able to edit anything in the file and to have access to the sidebar but I don't want them to have access to edit the script.

Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can publish it as an add-on. Or use a library to protect your code from changes (but they'd still be able to change the script in the spreadsheet, that would have the some stubs and hooks to the library).

Comment: Is there anyway I could publish it to only a select number of people?

Comment: use a library like Henrique says and then share the sheet to the selected users.